# Speeding up rails queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got a table that contains 10k products. When I query the database after a server restart, the server is querying all of the 10k products and then limits to 15 records in the response. Is this normal? It is causing my page to take 23 seconds for the first page to load. Upon the second request, everything looks better, but I still don't understand why the first query is grabbing all of those records.

My Query:

```
@products = Product.limit(15)
```

The first response:

```
Started GET "/admin/admin_products/" for 50.255.94.246 at 2017-05-31 17:43:49 +0000
Cannot render console from 50.255.94.246! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by AdminProductsController#index as HTML
/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/models/product.rb:96: warning: key :description is duplicated and overwritten on line 96
Product Load (5.7ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1000]]
Product Load (12.2ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE ("products"."id" > 1000) ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1000]]
Product Load (6.4ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE ("products"."id" > 2000) ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1000]]
Product Load (9.6ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE ("products"."id" > 3000) ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1000]]
Product Load (9.2ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE ("products"."id" > 4000) ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1000]]
Product Load (9.1ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE ("products"."id" > 5000) ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1000]]
Product Load (9.9ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE ("products"."id" > 6000) ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1000]]
Product Load (9.4ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE ("products"."id" > 7000) ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1000]]
Product Load (59.5ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE ("products"."id" > 8000) ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1000]]
Product Load (131.0ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE ("products"."id" > 9000) ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1000]]
Product Load (2.1ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE ("products"."id" > 10000) ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1000]]
  Rendering admin_products/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered layouts/_admin_portal.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Product Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 15]]
  Rendered collection of admin_products/_product.html.erb [15 times] (2.8ms)
  Rendered admin_products/_paginate.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered admin_products/index.html.erb within layouts/application (15.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_flash_messages.html.erb (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 23486ms (Views: 7643.7ms | ActiveRecord: 269.2ms)
```

The second time I execute the query:

```
Started GET "/admin/admin_products/" for 50.255.94.246 at 2017-05-31 
17:59:00 +0000
Cannot render console from 50.255.94.246! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 
127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by AdminProductsController#index as HTML
Rendering admin_products/index.html.erb within layouts/application
Rendered layouts/_admin_portal.html.erb (0.5ms)
Product Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 15]]
Rendered collection of admin_products/_product.html.erb [15 times] (2.7ms)
Rendered admin_products/_paginate.html.erb (0.6ms)
Rendered admin_products/index.html.erb within layouts/application (10.8ms)
Rendered layouts/_flash_messages.html.erb (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 26ms (Views: 23.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

Comment: Can you show the code in your product model? And do  you have any initializers that read your Product table?

Comment: I didn't think of that , but it makes sense. I had an integration in for elastic search which was causing the issue and forcing an import when the model was instantiated. I removed it and everything worked as expected. Thanks for pointing that out. @SteveTurczyn

Comment: Are you using a default scope?

Comment: This is a side note, but you should consider renaming `"/admin/admin_products/"` to just `/admin/products` to stick to rails convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SteveTurczyn pointed out my issue which ended up being rather simple. The problem involved calling an import function for Elastic Search which was in my Product model. After I removed the line of code, everything worked as expected. Here is the code that slowed down the process.

```
Product.includes(normal_model: [:normal_brand]).import force: true
```

I now have a controller method that invokes the import function when needed.